# Cant create branch in Git

Tags: git, github

Why I cant create branch using `$ git checkout -b Chapter 3 fatal: '3' is not a commit and a branch 'Chapter' cannot be created from it`   ?

I have already set remote repo on Master, however for some reason it doesnt let me to create local branch.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's because you have a space in there - spaces can mess up all sorts of things! Can you try:

`git checkout -b Chapter3`

I'm not sure why you would want a space in there. If `chapter3` is no good, how about `chapter-3` or `chapter_3`?